# Some users cannot log in on frontend

Tags: joomla-2.5, login, front-end

I have some users who are stuck in a loop where entering their login information redirects them back to the login page and nothing happens. A few were able to get around this by using another device or Google Chrome, but others cannot log in no matter what. Chrome on my PC works perfectly fine but I was able to replicate the issue on my phone (Safari). Recently a couple users are unable to register as well (as in they fill out the registration form but it loops them back to the registration page with fields blank).
Site is on Joomla 2.5 and cannot be upgraded.

Any help or ideas are appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Are you using any Two Factor Authentication plugins or ReCaptcha for the registration/login process?

Comment: "_Site is on Joomla 2.5 and cannot be upgraded._" ...sounds like a sad predicament. I think well need more diagnostics/details to be able possibly resolve this.  Please reply to Lodder's comment by editing the new information into your question.  Please also take our [tour] to earn your first badge.

Comment: Do you have Admin Tools installed?